# Display the count of total ids from an SQL in a class

Tags: php, sql

I am using three files to connect to each other:

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('dashboard.vc.php');
  echo $lstTotalCoupon['total_coupons'];
?>
```

**dashboard.vc.php**

```
<?php
  $routePath = "../";

  require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Product.mc.php");
  $mcProduct = new Product_MC();

  $lstTotalCoupon = $mcProduct->SelectCountProduct($db);

?>
```

**Product.mc.php**

```
<?php
Class Product_MC {
   public function SelectCountProduct($db) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT * AS total_coupons FROM product ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
  }
}
?>
```

I used the variable $lstTotalCoupon to get the select count from Product.mc.php, but I get the error

> Notice: Undefined index: total_coupons.

What seems to be missing?

Comment: It's a 2D array.

Comment: You can't specify a column alias for `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Product.mc.php**

```
<?php
Class Product_MC {
   public function SelectCountProduct($db) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT * AS total_coupons FROM product ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return count($rows);
  }
}
?>
```

This will return total count of fetched rows

OR you can even set it like this:

```
<?php
Class Product_MC {
   public function SelectCountProduct($db) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT * AS total_coupons FROM product ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
  }
}
?>
```

**dashboard.vc.php**

```
<?php
  $routePath = "../";

  require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Product.mc.php");
  $mcProduct = new Product_MC();

  $lstTotalCoupon = $mcProduct->SelectCountProduct($db);
  $lstTotalCoupon['total_coupons'] = count($lstTotalCoupon);
?>
```

So you will get it like this:

```
echo $lstTotalCoupon['total_coupons'];
```

Comment: I see you have to do the count and targeting the SQL, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the `SelectCountProduct()` like this :

```php
<?php
Class Product_MC {
   public function SelectCountProduct($db) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM product ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rows['total_coupons'] = $stmt->num_rows;
    return $rows;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to include the count of unique ids:

```
SELECT count(id) AS total_coupons FROM product
```

This will be more efficient than most answers as it's done in the DB engine.